# Is it possible to include layouts from subfolders within the layout folder in Xamarin?

Tags: xml, xamarin

I'm trying to assign a layout within the following code

```
<include
  layout="@layout/subfolder/boxes1_8" <!--The problem is here-->
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_columnWeight="1"
/>
```

located within an xml file stored in a sub folder[image]

I get an "invalid configuration '72' error.

How can I reference a layout from a subfolder within the layout folder with xml? Is it possible?

I've tried these formattings in xml.

```
layout="@layout/subfolder/boxes1_8"
layout="@layout/subfolder.boxes1_8"
layout="@(layout/subfolder/boxes1_8)"
```

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2741

Comment: @Jason Is it fair to say it isn't possible in VS? The first option for creating directories would be great but I'm using VS (I don't know java). And the other comments featuring code didn't work.

Comment: VS doesn't directly support it.  The comments make it sound like its possible by manually editing your csproj file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason has pointed it out, this is a feature request:[Make subfolders for android layout files possible #2741](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2741) that hasn't been implemented yet. You can follow up that thread: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2741.

As an alternative workaround provided by [erikpowa](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2741#issuecomment-470708668), you can try to edit the csproj file to include the layout like below:

```
<None Include="Resources\layout\subfolder\activity_main.axml" />

<AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\subfolder\activity_main.axml" Link="Resources\layout\activity_main.axml" Visible="false" />
```

Comment: I think they mentioned in the thread that doing that just hides both the files. Here's to hoping they implement this feature some day.